# Uber universal links (or deeplinks, url schemes or any other method) don't work on most of the phones

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

We had a Universal Link to Uber in our app for a while. About a month ago it stopped working (we didn't change anything). I even checked the official example link from the documentation, it has the same issues. We tested it on about 10 phones, on one of them it works, but other just open the AppStore page for Uber.

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I just tested a Universal link and it took me into the Uber app in the right place. Maybe post an example link that is not working for you?

Comment: Any link, including links from the official docs.

Comment: It works on some phones, yes.

Comment: Here's an issue on GitHub (it's about Uber SDK, but the problem is the same, deep links stopped working).

Comment: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/238